# How to get Image size from URL in ios

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, sdwebimage

How can I get the size(height/width) of an image from URL in objective-C? I want my container size according to the image. I am using `AFNetworking 3.0.`
I could use `SDWebImage` if it fulfills my requirement.

Comment: Download the image before setting-up the view?

Comment: There aren't any need to know size of image.Try to create UIImageView any size you want and change his content type(scaletofill, aspectfill, aspectfit etc)

Comment: From which URL you download the image? Many API for image service provide the height/width property in the fetched data(like json) You can have the look at the API Document.

Comment: What a requirement!! Please verify your requirement once again. I guess you are missing something.

Comment: Thanks to all above. Actually image is coming from my own server. But These are not of the same resolutions. Minimum is 800*800. But I need to know image size to update my image view accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

Knowing the size of an image before actually loading it can be necessary in a number of cases. For example, setting the height of a tableView cell in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method while loading the actual image later in the cellForRowAtIndexPath (this is a very frequent catch 22).

One simple way to do it, is to read the image header from the server URL using the Image I/O interface:

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

NSMutableString *imageURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myimageurl.com/image.png"];

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL], NULL);
NSDictionary* imageHeader = (__bridge NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSLog(@"Image header %@",imageHeader);
NSLog(@"PixelHeight %@",[imageHeader objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"]);
```

Comment: Great answer!  Helped me a lot.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4.x 
Xcode 12.x

```
func sizeOfImageAt(url: URL) -> CGSize? {
    // with CGImageSource we avoid loading the whole image into memory
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let propertiesOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
    guard let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, propertiesOptions) as? [CFString: Any] else {
        return nil
    }
    
    if let width = properties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as? CGFloat,
       let height = properties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as? CGFloat {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Asynchronous mechanism called GCD in iOS to dowload image without affecting your main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Download IMAGE using URL
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    // COMPOSE IMAGE FROM NSData
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // UI UPDATION ON MAIN THREAD
        // Calcualte height & width of image
        CGFloat height = image.size.height;
        CGFloat width = image.size.width;

    });
});
```

Comment: I am not downloading actually. I am using AFNetworking cachying like

[imageView setImageForState:UIControlStateNormal withURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultProductImage"]];

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 4** use this:

```
let imageURL = URL(string: post.imageBigPath)!
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL as CFURL,     
let imageHeader = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source!, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary;
print("Image header: \(imageHeader)")
```

The header would looks like:

> Image header: {
>       ColorModel = RGB;
>       Depth = 8;
>       PixelHeight = 640;
>       PixelWidth = 640;
>       "{Exif}" =     {
>           PixelXDimension = 360;
>           PixelYDimension = 360;
>       };
>       "{JFIF}" =     {
>           DensityUnit = 0;
>           JFIFVersion =         (
>               1,
>               0,
>               1
>           );
>           XDensity = 72;
>           YDensity = 72;
>       };
>       "{TIFF}" =     {
>           Orientation = 0;
>       }; }

So u can get from it the Width, Height.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:URL]; 
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
CGFloat height = image.size.height;
CGFloat width = image.size.width;
```

Comment: This is a synchronous way. It will stuck the UI until it gets the data.